# Nativescript app lags on device not emulator

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

This has been bugging me for a while and stopping me from publishing my app.

I have the following package.json file to show you the config and versions

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.pointdeveloper.myAmreli",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "2.4.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.2.1",
    "nativescript-admob": "^1.3.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "1.2.0",
    "nativescript-angular-snapshot": "1.2.0-5.2.361-2",
    "nativescript-camera": "^0.0.8",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-localstorage": "^1.1.0",
    "nativescript-master-technology": "^1.0.9",
    "nativescript-ng2-fonticon": "^1.3.4",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.2.2",
    "nativescript-phone": "^1.2.3",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^3.8.4",
    "nativescript-ripple": "^1.1.0",
    "nativescript-social-share": "^1.3.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.2",
    "nativescript-toast": "^1.4.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "tns-core-modules": "2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.20.0",
    "babel-types": "6.20.0",
    "babylon": "6.14.1",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-android-snapshot": "^0.*.*",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "zone.js": "~0.6.21"
  }
}
```

I have Android API 19 installed on my system as well as API 23.

When I test my app on Visual Studio Emulator (hyper-v) which is running API 19 the app works perfectly.

But as soon as I test my app on my device which has API 22 and on another device which has API 23 the app lags a lot..I mean a couple of seconds of lag between navigation.

What am I doing wrong here?

What is the rule of thumb as to which versions to build for and to deploy for?

Also, is there a way I can set min and max sdk versions in NativeScript.

-Thanks

Comment: If its lagging between navigation that can usually be remedied by checking logic you execute during navigation events and using the transitions correctly.

Comment: Brad - i've got the nav lag situation. Can you explain your comment.

Comment: @BradMartin There is nothing complex in navigation that I am doing..just passing some data using `routerextensions.navigate`. And by some data I mean a json object with a few values. I am receiving them in the other view. Also, if the logic was at fault it would lag everywhere, but as I mentioned It lags in the device and not the emulator..

Comment: Throw the device in the trash then :)

Comment: Hard to say what could be issue, have you tried several devices and see the same result? Or just one specific device

Comment: haha I am tempted to through it out.But I think the issue is that it is an x64 device as x64 is not yet supported by TNS that might be the issue..https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/requirements

Comment: @BradMartin can you tell me if is there a way to build a NS app for a spcefic API level. I want to support the lowest API at 19 kitkat. I tried doing `tns build android --compileSdk 19` but it failed as mentioned in this issue https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/2169

Comment: You can set min SDK in the AndroidManifest.xml - this link should help https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html